# Cannot register with any organization. Registering a system in RHEL

Tags: redhat, openstack, rhel

> subscription-manager register --username="USERNAME"
>   --password="PASSWORD"

when i run this command i'm getting error:- Cannot register with any organization.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue. But the problem got solved. Until you accept the terms & conditions AND you have active subscription 1, you can't register. I have solved this problem by adding company name as N/A and job title as retired. After 2 days of creating the account, active subscription became 1 and I was able to register my system.

> https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-enterprise-linux/evaluation
>   go to this link and try to login for 30 days evaluation.